# How to update string element in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list with string for each element. I'd like to change some element in the list and it didn't work. For example, I meant to change all elements from 2nd element to 'black'.

```py
list_string=['black','red','green','blue','gray']
list_string[1:]='black'
```

**Result:**

```py
['black', 'b', 'l', 'a', 'c', 'k']
```

**Expected:**

```py
['black','black', 'black', 'black', 'black']
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to change more than one element at a time?

Comment: ['black','black', 'black'', 'black', 'black']

Comment: Did you mean `list_string[1:]=['black']`?

Comment: `list_string[1:]=['black'] * 4`

Comment: Is slice assignment important here or are you just looking to set "the remaining" elements to some value? Do you care if you recreate your list or is inplace required

Comment: yes, I meant to replace elements within some locations like [ 2,5] or [3,4] to be 'black', and element should be 'black'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you would like to set a bunch of list values to some value based on slice notation. a `slice()` can be used and passed to a method. We might do:

```py
def set_by_index(my_list, slice, value):
    for index in range(len(my_list))[slice]:
        my_list[index] = value
```

Then:

```py
list_string=['black','red','green','blue','gray']
print(list_string)

set_by_index(list_string, slice(1, None), "foo")
print(list_string)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jon. It is what I wanted. I appreicated it.

Answer (score 3):

That [1:] assignment is a slice assignment.
It consumes a sequence.

Take a look at “list(‘black’)”
to better understand what happened.

Try something like this: “list_string[1:] = [‘black’, … , ‘black’]”

Comment: Thanks, using list_string[1:] = [‘black’, ‘red’], the list will only have 3 elements in total now, which i snot what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the followings:

```
for i in range(1,len(list_string)): list_string[i] = 'black'

print(list_string) #output: ['black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black']
```

Or

```
list_string = ['black' for x in list_string]
print(list_string) #Output: ['black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black']
```